# OneDrive API Link Sharing Options

Tags: onedrive

I'm currently working on an application that interacts with OneDrive. I've read [RESTful API manual](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/sharing_createLink.htm) and the only option available is to share document.

My questions are:

- Is there any way to remove or regenerate file sharing link?
- Is there any way to specify user emails to give an access to them?
- Is there any way to control this UI option "Recipients need to sign in with Microsoft Account"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to regenerate link to a file is to:

- Copy file "foo.docx" to "(Copy) foo.docx"
- Remove file "foo.docx"
- Rename "(Copy) foo.docx" to "foo.docx"
- Generate link for "foo.docx"

There is no way to specify emails for document access

There is no way to control this UI option "Recipients need to sign in with Microsoft Account"

Answer (score 1):

The sharing links that are created do not expire.  If you create a sharing link for a file that already shared, a HTTP 200 code will be returned.  At this time, createLink is only available but the user can remove the sharing permission from the OneDrive website.  Specific user access isn't currently supported.  Like the OneDrive website, any created link will not require sign-in.  I hope that helps.